# Datacontext lost with dynamic xaml in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, datacontext

I have a window with a simple frame element within it (we'll call it "myFrame"). Within the Window.Loaded I am parsing a string variable (loaded from an external source) with XamlReader.Parse(string) and the result is a Page object (local var is called "myPage"). I'm setting myFrame.Content = myPage.

Inside of the page is a label, like so:

```
<label Name="DataBindingTestLabel" Content="{Binding Path=TestLabel, TargetNullValue='Null value'}" />
```

I am trying to provide an anonymous type (for easy testing) as the frame's datacontext, like:

```
this.ContentFrame.DataContext = new { TestLabel = "Hello, world." };
```

I have verified that the DataContext property has the value after it's set and keeps the value for as long as I can step through the window's execution, but the value is lost sometime before the window is rendered and the fallback value, "Null value," is displayed.

After enabling databinding tracing, the output window in visual studio shows:

> System.Windows.Data Information: 41 : BindingExpression path error: 'TestLabel' property not found for 'object' because data item is null.  This could happen because the data provider has not produced any data yet. BindingExpression:Path=TestLabel; DataItem=null; target element is 'Label' (Name='DataBindingTestLabel'); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')

Any insight into something I'm doing wrong is most appreciated.

Comment: There has to be something more going on.  I wasn't able to reproduce in a project with just a label as you show and a DataContext set as to an anonymous type.

Comment: I agree. @Merick: Are you using dynamic xaml?

Comment: Smith - I'm not sure what you mean by dynamic xaml.  Do you mean you're creating WPF objects at runtime in C# code rather than xaml?

Comment: Exactly. Using the XamlReader.Parse() method, I'm taking a string of xaml and creating a control tree from it.

Comment: I tried another test using XamlReader.Parse(...) and it still worked succesfully.  My best guess is that neither the dynamic xaml nor the anonymous types are the problem and the problem is something/somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the frame element has issues dealing with data context while the content is a page element.

The solution was to use a more generic element (ContentControl) and instead of having the dynamic content be a Page element, we are using UserControl elements. In this setup, datacontext is not lost and binding works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone else can confirm this, since I've only been using anonymous types myself very recently, but the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) article on anonymous types seems to indicate that, as I suspected, your anonymous type is simply going out of scope. In the Remarks section of the page linked above, it says "An anonymous type has method scope," so I'm inclined to believe that's your problem.

Again, I'm not entirely sure, just thought I'd offer my thoughts on the matter...

Comment: This wasn't the case. I tried using it with a class I created.

Comment: Figures. 

To ask the stupid question: are you able to verify that the label is a child of the Page, and that the Page is a child of the Frame? I only ask because the Label cannot inherit the DataContext of the Frame if it's not in the Frame's tree. I'm sure this is like me saying "the sky is blue," but I tend to make stupid mistakes like that, myself...

Comment: Yeah. As stated, the label is inside of a page that is created from a string, then the whole page is set as the frame's content.